# jQuery prevent an image from being clicked on until other function is completed

Tags: jquery, click

I have a function preload.

I want to make it so that the image on my page does nothing when you click on it UNTIL the preloading has completed.

1. page loads
2. preloading begins - clicking on the main image does *nothing*
3. preloading completes - clicking on the main image will now call the intended function

How can this be realized?

Thanks

Comment: I could do this with a simple variable, but I just assumed there is a nicer way to do it with jQuery :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event handler

```
$('#myImage').load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the click event listener once the preloading is complete.

Answer (score 0):

write your logic in the call back function , so that it will wait it it completes

```
$("p").hide(1000,function(){
  alert("The paragraph is now hidden"); // write your code here
});
```

This should do for images

```
$(window).load(
    function() {
        // weave your magic here.
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When page loads:

```
var image = $('mainImage');
//this is your function binded to that image
image.bind('click', function() {
    //do stuff only when loaded is set to true    
    if ($(this).data('loaded') === true) {
        /your stuff
    }       
});
image.data('loaded', false);
```

Another way - in HTML set add class `not-loaded` to your image. And on `load` handler remove that class. And then your main image click handler must check, if class is set - if not, you can do your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered, but in situations where `$('img.someimage').load()` doesn't apply, here's a more general approach. This lets you assign the click handler, but the logic therein will only work when a variable representing state is set to true:

```
var loader = {
  isLoaded : false, // state
  clickHandler : function(){
    if( !loader.isLoaded ) return false;
    real_functionality_goes_here();
  },
  setLoaded : function( which ){ // utility function to turn handler on/off
    loader.isLoaded = !!which;   
  }
}
```

Then you'd have:

```
$('.your_element').click( loader.clickHandler );
```

Whatever the indicator is that represents readiness, you'd have it run:

```
loader.setLoaded(true); // turn handler on
loader.setLoaded( !loader.isLoaded ); // toggle handler on/off
```